# How to sort a column in ascending order with NULL values at the end?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm working on a personal database to track my projects.

I have a date/time column called `StartDate` in the table that I'm sorting in ascending order in the query that's used as the data source for the form where I'm entering data.

The form is a split form that displays the data in the "Detail" section in table format.

Until now, I have entered projects as they are assigned, but I have a need now to also track common projects that will be assigned but have not been assigned yet.

To track this, I wanted to enter the future projects without a start date.

However, when I enter the records like this, they are getting sorted to the top instead of at the bottom of the list where I prefer it.

Is there any way to override the sort so the records with a value in the `StartDate` column with sort ascending, but the records without a value in the `StartDate` column will sort at the end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you calculate anything on the date field, you'll loose the use of the index on that.

So check for *Null*:

```sql
SELECT 
    startdate, id
FROM 
    YourTable
ORDER BY
    StartDate Is Null,
    StartDate
```

Comment: Since I want the Null values to appear at the end, would I use `StartDate Is Null Desc`?

Comment: By choosing `Asc` or `Desc`, you can have the _Null_ entries sorted to the top or bottom as you like.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility would be to sort by this:

```sql
ORDER BY Nz([StartDate], CDate("31.12.2999"))
```

Here the function `NZ` is used to convert Null values ('on the fly', only in the query) to the date `31.12.2999` and so the sorting is as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated field to order your data.

I did a simple table (named `tbl`) with dates, some of them with blanks:

[image]

As you can see, rows with ID 4,5 and 9 are blanks in `StartDate`

Then I made up a query with a calculated field that will check if the field `StartDate` **is not** blank. If true, return 0, if false, return 1. That way all blank `Startdate` rows will return 1 and non blanks will return 0. Then order by this calculated field first and order by `StartDate` as second order field.

The formula of calculated field is:  `IIf(IsNull([StartDate])=False,0,1)`

The SQL code of query is:

```
SELECT tbl.startdate, tbl.id
FROM tbl
ORDER BY IIf(IsNull([StartDate])=False,0,1), tbl.startdate
```

I get this as output:

[image]

As you can see, rows with ID 4,5 and 9 are blanks in `StartDate`, and they are at bottom of recordset.

Hope you can adap this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Gustav's solution is great; however, it has a limitation. In my MS Access query, I have a DISTINCT in the SELECT clause to eliminate duplicate rows, and when using this solution, it returns error:
"ORDER BY clause ([column name] Is Null) conflicts with DISTINCT."
By removing the DISTINCT keyword, the query does run, and it sorts as this solution indicates.